# SQLite database problems

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have veritabani.java and i create database in this class. Then i create object in mainactivity.java. But when i run app. the program dont move database.java so i cant create database how i can solve this problem.

veritabani.java

```
    public class veritabani extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String VERİTABANİ_ADİ="kayit";
    public veritabani(Context c)
    {
        super(c,VERİTABANİ_ADİ,null,2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE kayit(ilacadi TEXT);");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST kayit");
        onCreate(db);   

    }
}
```

mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private veritabani v1;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        v1=new veritabani(this);
}
```

v1=new veritabani(this) doesnt work.

Comment: sorry here is the working link http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: go through this tutorial http://ashfaquedl.blogspot.in/search/label/SQLite%20database  you'll get basic tips and working example

Comment: Thank you too IPL and nEwbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
public class DBAdapter 
{
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GSDATA.db";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

private static final String CREATE_COVERPHOTO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS     COVERPHOTO (path Text,date DATE);";


private final Context context;
public String group;
private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private static SQLiteDatabase db;


public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_COVERPHOTO_TABLE);


        System.out.println("The Database is Created Here :");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS calSimpleNote");
        onCreate(db);
    }
} // database helper class complete

// ---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// ---closes the database---
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
    db.close();
}
```

// and write below line in main activity

```
DBAdapter adapter = new DBAdapter(MainActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "the program dont move database.java" but i had issues with databases using SQLiteOpenHelper.

Actually, SQLiteOpenHelper calls " public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)" only once, so if you change your tables between 2 launch, it won't be updated.

To solve this you have to manually delete the database by going into parameters / applications / [your_app] / erase data (or something like this) and try again.